# jQuery DOM manipulation with each();

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, this, each

I'm trying to do some simple DOM manipulation on several elements at once with jQuery using each(). I'm getting results that I don't understand.

Here is a jsFiddle that shows what I want to happen VS what actually happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/4T52A/2/

And here is the JS:

```
// Step One: Append one blue box within each grey box

$('.grey').append('<div class="blue"></div>');

// Step Two: Make one copy of the red box already there, and place it within the new blue box.

$('.grey').each(function () {
    $('.red', this).clone().appendTo('.blue', this);
});
```

Why am I getting the results I am, and how can I acheive the desired results?

Comment: This is how question should be asked! Clear, fiddle, proper formatting.

Comment: @dfsq totally agree, we can se that it is an experienced user that posted this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because context selector doesnt work in the `.append()`. The fastest solution (*not optimal*) is to recreate a new jQuery object :

```
$('.red', this).clone().appendTo($('.blue', this));
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4T52A/3/

Here an optimal solution :

```
$('.grey').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.red').clone().appendTo($this.find('.blue'));
});
```

Comment: Ok, so the whole problem is just that you can't use "this" within appendTo?

Comment: you can use `this`, just not as a context (because the appendTo method doesn't accept a context.) You could have done this for example: `$('.red', this).clone().appendTo($('.blue', this));` http://jsfiddle.net/4T52A/8/ (which is in this answer already)

Comment: @kthornbloom just like Kevin said, you can. To use context, you need to create another jQuery object. Like in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4T52A/6/

```
    // Step One: Append one blue box within each grey box

$('.grey').append('<div class="blue"></div>');

// Step Two: Make one copy of the red box already there, and place it within the new blue box.
 $('.grey').each(function () {
    var blue = $('.blue', this);
    $('.red', this).clone().appendTo(blue);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The appendTo doesn't work quite that way, personally I'd just use the `$(this)` object and grab what you want from there.

```
$('.grey').each(function () {                
    $(this).children('.red').clone().appendTo($(this).children('.blue'));
});
```

with a working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4T52A/9/)